# Iterate over unequal data frames to check if element of one dataframe exists in other

Tags: python, pandas

I have two unequal dataframes with multiple rows
df1 = ft1_hyp:

```
    assembly          non-redundant         name
1   GCF_000401195.1   WP_016197566.1        F-type
3   GCF_000401195.2   xx_01                 conjugative 
7   GCF_000401195.4   yy_02                 DUF1378
9   GCF_000401195.5   WP_004178060.1        HP1
15  GCF_000401195.7   zz_03                 HP3
```

df2 = same_hyp_prot:

```
    query           subject         HPSame
0   WP_000031677.1  WP_000031706.1  HPS_1
1   xx_01           WP_001330846.1  HPS_2
2   WP_000339857.1  WP_032417926.1  HPS_3
3   WP_000339857.1  WP_032426627.1  HPS_4
4   WP_000376615.1  yy_02           HPS_5
5   WP_000376615.1  WP_000376617.1  HPS_6
6   WP_000376615.1  WP_004883563.1  HPS_7
7   zz_03           WP_103826461.1  HPS_8
```

I am trying to find if df1 consists of df2's either subject or query present. If present then make a new column in df1 "NEW NAME" and put HPSame, else put name.
I want results as,
df1 =

```
    assembly            Non-redundant   name         NEW NAME
1   GCF_000401195.1     WP_016197566.1  F-type       F-type 
3   GCF_000401195.2     xx_01           conjugative  HPS_2
7   GCF_000401195.4     yy_02           DUF1378      HPS_5
9   GCF_000401195.5     WP_004178060.1  HP1          HP1
15  GCF_000401195.7     zz_03           HP3          HPS_8
```

I tried,

```
hp_filtered = pd.DataFrame(columns[])

for a, b in same_hyp_prot.iterrows():
        for c, d in ft1_hyp.iterrows():
            if b[0] or b[1] == d[1]:
                hp_filtered = hp_filtered.append({'assembly': d[0], 'non_redundant_refseq': d[1], 'name': d[2], 'New name': [b[2]]}, ignore_index=True)
```

which took a lot of time to complete and tried vectorizing it and throws me ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.

```
ft1_hyp.loc[(ft1_hyp['non-redundant'] == same_hyp_prot['query']) | (ft1_hyp['non-redundant'] == same_hyp_prot['subject']), 'NEW NAME'] = same_hyp_prot['HPSame']
ft1_hyp.loc[(ft1_hyp['non-redundant'] != same_hyp_prot['query']) & (ft1_hyp['non-redundant'] != same_hyp_prot['subject']), 'NEW NAME'] = ft1_hyp['name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can merge `left` *twice* on each column, renaming the column each time to `non-redundant` to make the merge clean.
2. Then, combine the three columns (`NEW NAME 1`, `NEW NAME 2` and `name`) using `fillna` and passing these columns. You will have to make sure that you do `fillna(df3['name'])` as the last `.fillna()`.

---

```
df3 = (pd.merge(df1,df2[['query','HPSame']].rename({'query' : 'non-redundant','HPSame' : 'NEW NAME 1'}, axis=1),
                how='left', on='non-redundant')
         .merge(df2[['subject','HPSame']].rename({'subject' : 'non-redundant','HPSame' : 'NEW NAME 2'}, axis=1),
                how='left', on='non-redundant'))
df3['NEW NAME'] = df3['NEW NAME 1'].fillna(df3.pop('NEW NAME 2')).fillna(df3['name'])
df3 = df3.drop('NEW NAME 1', axis=1)
df3
Out[1]: 
          assembly   non-redundant         name NEW NAME
0  GCF_000401195.1  WP_016197566.1       F-type   F-type
1  GCF_000401195.2           xx_01  conjugative    HPS_2
2  GCF_000401195.4           yy_02      DUF1378    HPS_5
3  GCF_000401195.5  WP_004178060.1          HP1      HP1
4  GCF_000401195.7           zz_03          HP3    HPS_8
```

Using `.pop()` is slightly fancy here; so, alternatively, you can probably just do something simpler to understand for the last two lines of code as well:

```
df3['NEW NAME'] = df3['NEW NAME 1'].fillna(df3['NEW NAME 2']).fillna(df3['name'])
df3 = df3.drop(['NEW NAME 1', 'NEW NAME 2'], axis=1)
```

Essentially, with `.pop()` you can drop a column AND `fillna()` in the same step. Or, you can just include it in the next line of code in `drop`, since you have to drop another column anyway.

Comment: Thank you David. Much appreciated.